# Putting text to border top of qlineedit

Tags: qt, qlineedit

I'm working in Qt 5.12. I should create a qlineedit shape in a form, like below:

[image]

But I can not write style sheet for it.

Comment: You might be better off putting the `QLineEdit` in a [`QGroupBox`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgroupbox.html) and applying a style to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I managed:

[image: the result]

I put QLineEdit into QGroupBox, and set a layout for QGroupBox. And set both horizontal and vertical policy to preferred for QLineEdit. My Style Sheet:

```css
QLineEdit{
    border: none;
    font: 10pt "Segoe UI";
}

QGroupBox {
     border: 1px solid #C4C4C4;;
     border-radius: 20px;
     margin-top: 10px
 }

 QGroupBox::title {
     subcontrol-origin: margin;
     subcontrol-position: top left; /* position at the top left */
     color: #C4C4C4;
     left: 15px;
 }
```